# Why our rishish followed grihastya ashrama but acharyas sanays asharama

Tags: sanyasi, grihastha

In mahabharata, adhi parva states agastya munu was advised to get married and beget children.but all of our acharayas like sankara, ramanuja and madhvacharya taken sanyasa ashrama, so which is appropriate according to scrpture.is grihastya ashrama compulsory according to advise given to agastya muni or we can move to sanayas ashram at any stage like our acharyas?

Comment: The rishis are also acharyas and sanyasi acharyas are rishis. The two states are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Acharyas are not Rishis (Seers). Rishi =To whom Veda mantras (or Riks inparticular) are revealed. Rishis were married  mostly because in Vedic Dharma spouse is indispensable. In Homas they accompany their husbands. Sannyas however is not even mentioned in the Vedas.